# Bypass Credential dialog box of internet explorer

Tags: c#, internet-explorer, credentials

My c# application opens the Internet explorer for different web URL/ domains.
And I have all those credential information (username, password and domain name) stored in the database for each web application.
Now how I can authenticate automatically without entering credential in “Network Credential” dialog box using code or bypass that dialog box? In other words I need to store those credential on system so no need to enter.
I am using c#

Answer (score 0):

You could use the http://user:password@protected-url.com/somepage.html, but this will store the info a the browser's history.